# chanding contents of spinners run-time (android), tried and failed

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I recently posted a question on how to change the values of a spinner during program execution and was told to change the array used to make the adaptor and call notifyDataSetChanged();

I tried that but my spinner is not getting updated even though my array is. I attach the code below

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    res=getResources();
    Boolean a;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

// First spinner whose value determines the value of the second spinner        
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
// ArrayAdaptor of first spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this                            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setVisibility(4);// spinner 2 is not visible initially
// ArrayAdaptor of first spinner        
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner_drop);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        if(pos!=0)
        {

     //copying string array of second spinner from strings.xml to the current string array
      spinner_drop=res.getStringArray(R.array.activities_array2);
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +spinner_drop[0] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this toast shows up
      adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
      spinner2.refreshDrawableState();
      spinner2.setVisibility(0);//this command works and the spinner is visible, but it is empty
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) 
    {
      // Do nothing.
    }


}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong any ideas will help.

PS: I have tried removing the entire invisible, visible thing, doesnt help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `onItemSelected` method as follows, note the *new addition* I added below.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
  if (pos!=0) {

    //copying string array of second spinner from strings.xml to the current
    //string array
    spinner_drop=res.getStringArray(R.array.activities_array2);
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +spinner_drop[0],
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this toast shows up
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2); // <--- New Addition
    // spinner2.refreshDrawableState();
    spinner2.setVisibility(0); //this command works and the spinner is visible,
                               //but it is empty
  }
}
```